# How do I return a specific line from a file if it partially matches a string parameter? [C]

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I am new to C but I am trying to write a function that returns a line from a file depending on the parameter used. It will return the last line that contains that parameter. I think it's better explained using an example:

Here is the contents of the file:

```
1 one onehello
2 two twohello
3 one threehello
```

So, if I call the function like this:

```
lineContaining("one")
```

It should return "one threehello"

Here is what I have so far, it also includes a main function that tests the function:

```
char *readStringedCommand(char *str1)
{
    int size = 1024;
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    char *result = malloc(size);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, 1024, fp)) //get a line from a file
    {
            printf("while1 entered: %s", buffer);
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            while(buffer[i] != '\n') //read all the way to the end of a line
            {
                    printf("while2 entered: %s", buffer+i);
                    k = i;
                    while(buffer[k]==str1[j]) //while two characters match
                    {
                            printf("while3 entered");
                            k++;
                            j++;
                            strcat(result, buffer+k); //append the character to the result

                            if(str1[j] = '\0') //if the next character of str1 is the last one
                            {
                                    strncat(result, buffer+k, 20); //append the rest of buffer to the result
                                    return result;
                                    printf("result = %s", result);
                            }
                    }

                    result[0] = '\0'; //clear result for the next line
                    j = 0; //set str1's position to 0
                    k = 0;
                    i++;
            }

    }
    return "errorrrrrr";
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int num1 = 1;
    char str1[] = "one onehello";
    int num2 = 2;
    char str2[] = "two twohello";
    int num3 = 3;
    char str3[] = "one threehello";
    hwrite(num1, str1); //a function I made that writes a line to a file
    hwrite(num2, str2);
    hwrite(num3, str3);
    printf("%s", readStringedCommand("one"));
    return 0;
}
```

Okay, the function gives me an error:

```
while1 entered: 1 one onehello
while2 entered: 1 one onehello
while2 entered:  one onehello
while2 entered: one onehello
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Considering it gives me the error at the third while loop, I think the problem is there. I unfortunately don't know what is wrong here. I am sure there are more errors after that point but this one is confusing me.

MY QUESTIONS:

1. **How do I fix this segmentation error?**
2. **The code is obviously very ugly but I suck at C. Is there a better way to solve this question?**

Thanks for reading all of this and I would appreciate some help. =(

EDIT: After fixing some errors suggested by you guys, I no longer get the segmentation error. The function returns " onehello" instead, which is wrong. It should return "one threehello". But I am making progress, and for that I am thankful.

Comment: One problem is `strcat(result, buffer+k); //append the character to the result`. The comment is wrong, that line appends the entire remainder of the string in `buffer` from `buffer[k]` on to `result`.

Comment: You are right, I think `strcat(result, buffer[k])` might be the right way but it is giving me an error: `passing argument 2 of ‘strcat’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: `strcat` is not the right thing for that. If you want to append character for character, keep an index and `result[index++] = buffer[k];` - don't forget to 0-terminate at the end. But that is probably still not a good way to achieve what you want. Unfortunately, your code confuses me. I could give a concise solution for what I think the text asks for, but I can't reconcile that with the code.

Comment: So let's try to clarify. You want to read a file, and find the last line int it that contains a given string as a substring, is that it? (So for example, `readStringedCommand("one")` would _not_ return `"opened"`, since the characters of `"one"` are not contiguous in that?)

Comment: @Daniel I think that was where I was getting the segmentation error, I changed the strcat function to `result[j] = buffer[k]` and I am not getting that error anymore. To answer your question, Yes it will not return "opened". I'll edit the original post with more information of where I am at.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(str1[j] = '\0')
```

should be

```
 if(str1[j] == '\0')
```

you probably want to compare values

the loop `while(buffer[i] != '\n')` might not exit if your file is missing a newline character, what might happen in the last line of in .txt file.

Comment: I completely missed that!!

Comment: @Sheer, but it doesnt loop to the EOF, that while loop only goes to the end of the line.

Comment: @LilyBanks yeah, you got a point.Let's see what Armin got to say.I too don't see how can we think of another line without a newline character in the first line.

Comment: @Sheer I am almost 100% positive there is a new line character after each line.

Comment: @LilyBanks Me too.Its after all lines that the EOF comes.I should be more careful before I jump to upvote answers

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your problem correctly, your goal can be achieved in a much simpler way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readStringedCommand(char *str1)
{
    int size = 1024;
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    char *result = malloc(size);
    /* Check allocations */
    if (!buffer || !result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Allocation failure, exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    result[0] = 0; // 0-terminate result

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    /* Check whether file was opened successfully */
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while(fgets(buffer, size, fp)) //get a line from a file
    {
        if (strstr(buffer, str1)) { // Check whether the line contains the needle
            strcpy(result, buffer); // Copy the line if it does
        }
    }

    // close file
    fclose(fp);

    // Free memory we don't need anymore
    free(buffer);

    // Now, what if no line contained the needle?
    if (result[0] == 0) {
        // Hmm, maybe
        free(result);
        return NULL; // ?
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Just use `strstr` from the standard library to check whether `str1` is contained in each line, copy each line that contains it to `result`, ignore the others. Then at the end, `result` contains the last line that contained `str1` - if any.

If you don't want the entire line, but only the part starting at the first occurrence of `str1`, capture the pointer that `strstr` returns, and use that as the source for the `strcpy`:

```
char *needle;
if ((needle = strstr(buffer, str1))) {
    strcpy(result, needle);
}
```